# SQL - ISNULL then compare to a string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table aaa (ID nvarchar(80), Is_enduser varchar(5), identityy int)
create table bbb (ID varchar(90), Is_enduser bit, identityy int)
insert into aaa values (null, 'False',1),(null, 'False',2), (null, 'True',3)
insert into bbb values ('*N/A', 0,1),('*N/A', 0,2),('*N/A', 1,3)
```

So I have two table with differnt value, but they actually have the  same meaning, null = *N/A
and 'True' = 1 and 'False' = 0

So I want to compare the data in these two table

The way i'm doing it is using Cursor to compare it row by row, I use table 'aaa' as base table at first time

```
declare c cursor for 
select  isnull(ID,'*N/A'), 
    case is_enduser when 'False' then '0' when 'True' then '1' end,
    identityy
    from aaa
open c
    declare @ID nvarchar(80), @is_enduser varchar(5), @identityy int
    fetch next from c into @ID, @is_enduser, @identityy
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            begin
            if exists (select ID,  convert(varchar(5), is_enduser, identityy)  from bbb
            where ID = @ID and Is_enduser = @is_enduser and identityy = @identityy)
                Print 'Find Match'
            else 
                print 'no match'
            End
        fetch next from c into @id, @is_enduser, @identityy
        end
close c
deallocate c
```

When I want to use 'bbb' as my base table to compare, I couldn't get the result I want

```
declare b cursor for
select  ID , is_enduser, identityy from bbb
open b
declare @ID varchar(20), @is_enduser varchar(20), @identityy int
fetch next from b into @ID, @is_enduser, @identityy
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        Begin
        IF EXISTS ( select ISNULL(ID, '*N/A'), 
        case is_enduser when 'False' then '0' when 'True' then '1' end identityy from aaa
        where ID = @ID and is_enduser = @is_enduser and identityy = @identityy)
            print 'find match'
        else 
            print 'no match'
        End
        fetch next from b into @ID, @is_enduser, @identityy
    End
close b
deallocate b
```

So my second cursor cannot find the match, I tried to print the value of both string they are actually the same but they are not matched
Please help, Thanks

UPDATED - SOLUTION - in second cursor, change the statement to

```
IF EXISTS ( select ID, Is_enduser, identityy from aaa
where ISNULL(ID,'*N/A') = @ID 
and case is_enduser when 'False' then '0' when 'True' then '1' end = @is_enduser
and identityy = @identityy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ID = @ID` in second cursor to `ISNULL(ID,@ID) = @ID`